# Unable to use JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have attempted to use JSON.NET, installed it via NuGet and tried to include it into the project using the using statement. It's not even showing up in the list of namespaces.

I then decided to go with the ASP.NET Web Api libraries that has JSON support. Again I tried to include it using the using statement, no namespace. Even though it's installed.

```
using System.Json;
```

Also tired

```
using System.Net.Json;
```

I'm using C# 5 and .NET 4.5. How can I get one of these packages to work? As stated both are installed via NuGet. There's no Namespace for them showing up in intellisense.

Comment: Show what you tried, and what does (not) work. This is vague and argumentative.

Comment: [OOTB functionality in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: And whoat assemblies are referenced? You can open the references pseudo-folder to check.

Comment: To those that placed it on hold. I think you will find the downvotes and close votes were because of the rant I included, I removed it. This question is no longer off topic at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace you are looking for is:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: coolio, I know i used to have problems adding new references, no-one ever mentions the usings :p